# How to get the data through the map and put it in the state

Tags: reactjs, axios

I wanted to use Axios get to put the contents value of 'card' and call the data and put the value in 'wordAll', but it failed.
I want to combine and store the arrays I received as an axios in the state through the map function.
Sometimes the code I wrote comes in and sometimes it doesn't. I know my code is wrong.

Please teach me the way.

```
const [wordAll, setWordAll] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  cards.map((contents) => {
    axios
      .get(`https/api/words/detail_list/?contents=${contents.contents}`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: cookies.token,
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        let indata = res.data;
        for (var i = 0; i < indata.length; i++) {
          wordAll.push(indata[i]);
          setWordAll(wordAll);
        }
        console.log('wordAll0', wordAll);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('err==>', error);
      });
  });
}, []);
console.log('wordAll1', wordAll);
```

Comment: You're mutating the state instead of setting a new one. Try `.then((res) => { setWorldAll(res.data); })`. But don't expect the new state to print in the console right away -- it will update on the next render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the cards axios request promises in an array (`cardsPromises`) and then use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to get the values from the resolved promises.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const cardsPromises = cards.map((contents) =>
    axios.get(`https/api/words/detail_list/?contents=${contents.contents}`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: cookies.token
      }
    })
  );

  Promise.all(cardsPromises)
    .then((resp) => {
      //resp will be an array of resolved values
      setWordAll(resp);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("err==>", error);
    });
}, []);
```